# php open and close a div every 5 iterations

Tags: php, html, foreach, modulus

How would I go about gett my code below to out 5 `.choice` elements in a `.row` element

```
        <?php
        $count = 0;

        foreach($imp_photos['data'] as $photo)
        {
            $count = ($count + 1)%5;
            if ($count == 0) {

        ?>
                <div class="choice">
                    <input type="checkbox" name="photos[]" value="<?php echo $photo->id; ?>" class="fb_checkbox"><img src="<?php echo $photo->picture; ?>" class="clear" />
                </div>

        <?php
        }
        else
        {
        ?>
            <div class="choice">
                <input type="checkbox" name="photos[]" value="<?php echo $photo->id; ?>" class="fb_checkbox"><img src="<?php echo $photo->picture; ?>" class="clear" />
            </div>

        <?php
        }
        }

        ?>
```

I know I have to do some with `%` but I cannot get it working.

Comment: Why not use a `<table>` to display tabular data?

Comment: I would still have to open close a `<tr>` every 5 `<td>`'s so my question still stands

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Untested, but should do the trick

```
<?php
    //Prepare the data
    $rows = array();
    $row = array();
    $rowSize = 5;
    foreach($imp_photos["data"] AS $photo) {
        $choice = array(
            "id" => $photo->id,
            "picture" => $photo->picture;
        );
        $row[] = $choice;

        if(sizeof($row) == $rowSize) {
            $rows[] = $row;
            $row = array();
        }
    }
?>

<!-- display the data -->
<?php foreach($rows AS $row) { ?>
    <div class="row">
        <?php foreach($row AS $choice) { ?>
            <input type="checkbox" name="photos[]" value="<?php echo $choice["id"]; ?>" class="fb_checkbox"><img src="<?php echo $choice["picture"]; ?>" class="clear" />
        <?php } //foreach row ?>
    </div>
<?php } //foreach $rows ?>
```

Comment: Although I must say I am not sure if I understood the question right.
Nevertheless, first preparing the data and then output it separately is always a good idea, since it separates the tasks (generate data vs display data) and makes debugging easier.

Answer (score 2):

The way you're calculating count is wrong. It becomes 1 -> .20 -> 1.20 -> .24... This is a bit more of a straightforward way of doing it.

```
$count++;
if($count%5 == 0) { /* Do your div stuff here */ }
```

Comment: That is called the [modulus operator](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.arithmetic.php). It's well worth knowing!